# Solve for mean & variance of random variable given mean & variance of sum

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Consider a sum of $n$ samples of a single independent normal random variable $X$, where $X$ follows the normal distribution $N(\mu$, $\sigma)$, where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the variance.

As far as I can understand from [this reference](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/172), the mean of the sum would be $n\mu$ and the variance of the sum is $n^2\sigma^2$.

Does this mean that the opposite is true? In other words, can we use those two equations to solve for the mean and variance of the random variable, given the mean and variance of the sum?

Comment: I't _not_ a "sum of $n$ samples" but a sum of _one_ sample consisting of $n$ observations -- a sample of size $n. \qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know that $Z = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ is a sum of $n$ i.i.d. $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$ random variables, then yes.
To see why, denote by $\mu_Z$ and $\sigma_Z$ the mean and variance of $Z$. 
Then, by the linearity of expectation,
$$
\mu_Z = \mathbb{E}[Z] = \mathbb{E}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_1] + \cdots + \mathbb{E}[X_n] = n\mu.
$$
Similarly, by the linearity of variance,
$$
\sigma_Z = \operatorname{Var}[Z] = \operatorname{Var}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] = \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \cdots + \operatorname{Var}[X_n] = n\sigma^2.
$$

Comment: When you use \operatorname{Var} instead of \text{Var} then you get proper spacing in both $a\operatorname{Var} X$ and $a\operatorname{Var}(X)$ (where you see that the space to the right of $\operatorname{Var}$ is smaller in the second example -- thus depends on the context). That's one of the reasons \operatorname{Var} is standard.

Comment: I did not realize operatorname was an option here. Fixed.